# Swipe to delete, ripple effect on background

Tags: android, swipe

I want to add this ripple effect when card view is swipe.
How i can achieve this?
Here's the video i'm questioning, nowhere can't find answer.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1vNFnrquuFFOVJPSlJKY0I1bDdYY21mYjRqQlFqWFYwZHl3/view?usp=sharing

I already maked swipeAdapter i just need that ripple effect when swiping is started. Here's my code: 
pastebin.com/zGfmmbwm, and interface for listener, pastebin.com/9JzX1yhC

, do i need to create some interface for listener when swiping ?

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout.
If u get stuck, please feel free to comment.

Comment: I already maked swipeAdapter i just need that ripple effect when swiping is started.  Here's my code: https://pastebin.com/zGfmmbwm, and interface for listener, https://pastebin.com/9JzX1yhC  , do i need to create some interface for listener when swiping ?

Comment: I think yes, you need to identify the event of swipe & then set the animation or ripple background to the layout which appeared after swiping the row of your RecyclerView.

Answer (score 0):

> i just need that ripple effect when swiping is started

There can be so many ways it can be done but the simplest one is to add ripple background to your `CardView`, that is, when user touches the `cardView` the ripple will be shown.

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?selectableItemBackground"/>
```

The logic is whether the user wants to just see the content or want to swipe, he has to touch the Card, which it turn will add the ripple effect.

Comment: Swipe is different than clicking. Your code adds the ripple effect for clicking only. Doesn't work for swiping.